# Create HTML table from server side

Tags: asp.net, tags, html-table

I have stored my tags in the SQL Server database,
TABLE NAME: Tags
COLUMNS

- TagID
- TagName
- TagURL

Now I want to create a list like below in the aspx page, created from the database. I have done the work of keeping all the tags and tagURL from the database in a dataset. But I have no idea how to create dynamic HTML list or asp.net list from database.

I have to create list like this:

```
<ul>
            <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li> 
            <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a></li>

            <li class="tag3"><a href="#">Consectetur adipiscing elit</a></li>
            <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Proin </a></li>
            <li class="tag4"><a href="#">Sagittis libero</a></li>
            <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Aliquet augue</a></li>
            <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Quisque dui lacus</a></li>
            <li class="tag5"><a href="#">Consequat</a></li>

            <li class="tag2"><a href="#">Dictum non</a></li>
            <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Venenatis et tortor</a></li>
            <li class="tag3"><a href="#">Suspendisse mauris</a></li>
            <li class="tag4"><a href="#">In accumsan </a></li>
            <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Egestas neque</a></li>
            <li class="tag5"><a href="#">Mauris eget felis</a></li>

            <li class="tag1"><a href="#">Suspendisse</a></li>
            <li class="tag2"><a href="#">condimentum eleifend nulla</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Where

```
>  class="tag <random number from 1-5>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to use something like an asp.net repeater.  Here is an example from the msdn library while I write up a more suitable one.

[Digging Into the Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx#aspnet-whenusedatawebcontrols_topic5)

This is my understanding of your requirements.  I'm not sure if the random number generation could be handled better.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="<%# String.format("tag{0}", GetRandom())%>"><a href="<%# Eval("TagUrl") %>"><%# Eval("TagName")%></a></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
Private _random As Random
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        _random = New Random

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("TagName")
        dt.Columns.Add("TagUrl")


        dt.Rows.Add("Test1", "TestUrl1")
        dt.Rows.Add("Test2", "TestUrl2")
        dt.Rows.Add("Test3", "TestUrl3")
        dt.Rows.Add("Test4", "TestUrl4")
        dt.Rows.Add("Test5", "TestUrl5")

        Repeater1.DataSource = dt
        Repeater1.DataBind()

    End If


End Sub

Protected Function GetRandom() As Integer
    Return _random.Next(1, 5)
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am getting message of "string' does not contain a definition for 'format"  ... at <li class="<%# String.format("tag{0}", GetRandom())%>">
           <a href="<%# Eval("TagUrl")%>"> <%# Eval("TagName")%></a>
           </li>

Comment: @Chris That's a strange one. Are you using ASP.NET WebForms? C#/VB? You can also try doing this instead <li class="<%= "tag" & GetRandom() %>"> This code is obviously VB.NET but I've just tested it under c# ok.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a repeater as well. However there are two more options:

1. Create a custom web control for this purpose
2. Use a literal control and assign the html to its Text property. Not very elegant, but might work if you just want a quick-and-dirty solution. Remember to set the literals Mode-property to "Passthrough" in order to allow html-tags.